# Flutter and Bottom Overflowed

Tags: dart, flutter, material-design

Here's my problem:

[image]

How can I create a card for each item where I don't have to worry about the number of Fields that will be on each Item without Overflowing?

From what I understand the card in this case is a square box.

Comment: Do you want a gridview with different sizes for child? take a look at this package  :  https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view

Comment: No. I want to be able to add more info on each Card and not have the message of bottom Overflowed

Comment: ok, so you just have to change the childAspectRatio property from the GridView widget

Comment: Are you sure a fixed Card layout is the right UI for you? Users may be increasing their font size to make text more readable, and then you may break your UI again. The staggered grid suggestion by @diegoveloper is a good way, or perhaps you display the text on top of the image (pinned to a corner..)

Comment: The main problem is that I am using Flutter Pagewise Package (https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_pagewise) because I need to get data as JSON from an external server 10 at the time. I will look into Staggered grid to see if it fits my app.

Answer (score 0):

Overflow errors on the UI are usually occurs when the children inside the widget exceeds their parent's dimension, unless the children inside the parent widget was wrapped with a Scrollable. A workaround that you can apply here is by using [IntrinsicHeight](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html) as a parent widget to dynamically adjust its dimension base from its child widget, and use ConstrainedBox as IntrinsicHeight widget's child to set a minimum dimension for the items.

```dart
IntrinsicHeight(
  child: ConstrainedBox(
    constraints: const BoxConstraints(
      /// Set minimum height for the item
      minHeight: 100,
    ),
    /// child widget with dynamic height goes here
    child: Container(),
  ),
),
```

Or if you're looking for a staggered Grid, there's a plugin for this use case: [flutter_staggered_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view)